# change boostrap dropdown design

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap v4.5.0 and I am currently working on a dropdown.

I try to change a little the design of the dropdown, but there is a problem.
When I click, the dropdown appears too much down, you can see that there is a loot of space (on the bottom).

Why is that?

Btw: use 'full page' on the snippet code and also i don't know why on the snippet the background-color of the dropdown-menu is not applied, on my localhost is working.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap);

:root {
    --main-color: #4D6275;
    --second-color: #3F5060;

    --body-bg: #2E3841;
    --box-bg: #272F37;

    --text-color: #D5D5D5;
    --grey-color: #B2B2B2;
    --simple-color: #C3C3C3;

    --content-height: 92px;
    --space-top: 30px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.box-account {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    /*transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;*/
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.box-account-name {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*
.box-account-name i {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
*/

.nav-account-avatar-display {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3.5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.nav-account a {
    color: #D5D5D5;
}

.box-account:hover {
    background-color: #3F5160;
    /*transform: translateY(-10%);*/
}


.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #4D6275;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #3F5160;
    color: #D5D5D5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?">
        
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">

<!-- Load sweetalert2 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<!-- Google Font -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">

<a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="box-account">
        <div class="box-account-name">
            <span class="name-account-nav">Name</span>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/02/3e/eb/023eebc4bcee84dda420da10d3fe1c91.jpg" class="nav-account-avatar-display">
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
                    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: block` to the menu expander. This will fix the vertical offset. Still, 5px left offset will be applied, you can either try to figure out what forces js to think there is a 5px overflow on the left or you can just set `margin-left: -5px` to `.dropdown-menu`. This will work in case it's not overwritten by imported boostrap.css

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap);

:root {
    --main-color: #4D6275;
    --second-color: #3F5060;

    --body-bg: #2E3841;
    --box-bg: #272F37;

    --text-color: #D5D5D5;
    --grey-color: #B2B2B2;
    --simple-color: #C3C3C3;

    --content-height: 92px;
    --space-top: 30px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--body-bg);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.box-account {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    /*transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;*/
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.box-account-name {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*
.box-account-name i {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
*/

.nav-account-avatar-display {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3.5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.nav-account a {
    color: #D5D5D5;
}

.box-account:hover {
    background-color: #3F5160;
    /*transform: translateY(-10%);*/
}

.menu-button {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #4D6275;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #3F5160;
    color: #D5D5D5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?">
        
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">

<!-- Load sweetalert2 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<!-- Google Font -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">

<a href="#" role="button" class="menu-button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="box-account">
        <div class="box-account-name">
            <span class="name-account-nav">Name</span>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/02/3e/eb/023eebc4bcee84dda420da10d3fe1c91.jpg" class="nav-account-avatar-display">
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
                    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is working perfectly! About the margin, on localhost is working perfectly without adding -5px margin, but on snippet code I don't know for some reason is not working correctly, probably because I have more code (css/html) on localhost.